# Monaca Onsen UI - Beginners tutorials

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui, monaca

I cant find walkthroughs for monaca onsen ui. Most are advance tutorials that a beginner cannot understand. Angular, Jquery , and plain javascript are mixed so i get confused which is which.

I want to save something to my backend. I followed their tutorials but i got lost.

Onsen is a nice framework, but without walkthrough tutorials, how will programmers learn?

Comment: Perhaps reading this http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html

If you have some other question, please be more specific.

Comment: If you are completely new to JavaScript, I recommend you to learn pure JavaScript first, before proceeding to advanced frameworks.

Comment: hi @fran-dios , im asking too much, but i wish someone will make a youtube about monaca backend memo .

Answer (score 3):

May I suggest using a few links. I would try building this sample app through monaca. "Backend Memo" 
http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/en/sampleapp/samples/backend_memo/

This is a good start to manipulate data. Keep in mind that you can have onsen ui, jquery, and angular js all working together within a single application. The onsen ui guide is helpful http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html
and so it the http://onsen.io/reference/javascript.html --> for all categories you can go here for onsen ui http://onsen.io/docs.html

But when it comes to monaca I strongly advise trying out some sample applications, your going to make mistakes but it will help you learn. http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/en/learning/ is helpful for overall understanding.

But Key thing that I found helpful was to actually use the search bar in the monaca docs to find certain keywords. It helped me find certain collection tasks that I needed help with. 
And bottom line - if its installed correctly you can use it. Calling the proper js from html will come after a while. example if you have the onsen framework and several aspecs of jquery installed in your application and called in your index - you can call either or parameters. The output will be on how you layer them together.

Comment: hi @john-gonzalez ,  i followed that backend memo , but really cant run it successfully. If only there was a youtube video about that .

Comment: is all of the app showing? is it ONLY not accessing the backend? - if so it may be your js. You may have to assign your memo id - var currentMemoID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" at the begining; which you can get from your config xml "<preference name="monaca:MonacaBackendId..."

Comment: as a noob, i had no idea that i need to replace currentMemoID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" .  As if their documentation said that.

Comment: I had the same issue, we all start somewhere - hopefully it takes. I am pretty sure that is what I used to get mine finally working, but I did for sure have issues connecting the backend memo following the documentation alone. Let me know if it works